# tufte-handout font problem

Tags: fonts, tufte

I am trying to use tufte-handout class for a document. I have the required packages installed. I am trying to compile the sample tex (sample-handout.tex) file from the project site http://code.google.com/p/tufte-latex/downloads/detail?name=tufte-latex-3.5.0.zip.

But I am getting problems with font generation. The log file is appended below. It seems to not being able to generate some fonts:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 0+408/600 --dpi 408 fvmr8r
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for fvmr8r. 
mktexpk: perhaps fvmr8r is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file fvmr8r): Font fvmr8r at 408 not found
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I have tried `udpmap-sys` and also `updmap --enable Map=pazo.map`
`updmap --enable Map=fpls.map`. But the error persists. Any ideas?

Comment: You are missing the [Bera Sans Mono font](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/bera/).  The best way to fix this depends on your platform and how you have installed TeX.

Comment: I have texlive on Fedora 19. texlive-bera is already installed on my system.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tip. Solved with updmap --enable Map=bera.map

Comment: I was just going to suggest that.

Comment: Just one more thing to ask how was fvmr8r linked to bera?

Comment: in `bera.map` there is a line `fvmr8r BeraSansMono-Roman " TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <8r.enc <fvmr8a.pfb`

Comment: Did you solve the problem with that?

Answer (score 3):

Solved with the command

```
$updmap --enable Map=bera.map
```

Comment: This worked to me:
sudo updmap -sys --enable Map=bera.map